# ¿Cómo puedo saber si al menos uno de los checkboxes en mi formulario estan en estado activado?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo varios checkboxes y necesito que el boton de submit se active con al menos un checkbox checado, estoy utilizando esta función:

```
 $("input:checkbox").on('change', function() {
    $('#sub').prop("disabled", !this.checked)
  }).trigger('change');
```

Donde sub es el id del boton a deshabilitar o habilitar, pero cuando selecciono tres checkboxes y deselecciono uno, se deshabilita el boton nuevamente y necesito que se deshabilite solo cuando no este ningún checkbox checado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu lógica puede estar bien, pero hace falta condicionarlo, mejor te propongo la siguiente lógica:

Maneja todos tus elementos checkbox por una única clase para que sean mas sencillos de referenciar, pon predeterminado el atributo `disabled` en tu botón, luego dentro de tu función change crea una variable que obtenga el total de elementos :checked con `.length` y luego condiciona que si la variable nueva no es igual a 0, eliminar el atributo `disabled` de tu boton, de lo contrario volver al estado natural.

> Ejemplo:

```js
$(".check").on("change", function(){

  //Agregamos una variable fija para comprobar la cantidad de elementos chekeados.
  
  var checked = $(".check:checked").length;
  
  //Condicionamos de manera que se ejecute si hay un elemento seleccionado o la cantidad de elementos en check no es igual a 0.

  if (checked != 0) {
  
    //Agregamos un poco de css.
  
    $("#boton").css({"color": "black"});
    
    // Quitamos el atributo disabled.
    
    $("#boton").removeAttr("disabled");
    $("h5").html("El boton esta activo.");
  
  }else{
  
    $("#boton").css({"color": "#d1d1e0"});
    
    //Agregamos el atributo disabled y lo seteamos en disabled.
    
    $("#boton").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $("h5").html("El boton esta inactivo.");
  
  }

});

$("#boton").click(function(){

  //Comprobamos la efectividad de la funcion probando el boton.

  $("h5").html("Hiciste click en el boton.");

});
```

```css
#boton {

  background-color: #f0f0f5; 
  border: solid 1px #e0e0eb;
  color: #d1d1e0;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="check" type="checkbox">
<input class="check" type="checkbox">
<input class="check" type="checkbox">

<button id="boton" disabled="disabled">Enviar</button>
<h5>El boton esta inactivo.</h5>
```

Como ves, el botón es clickeable solo cuando uno o mas inputs estan seleccionados.

Espero que te sea de ayuda, un saludo.

Answer (score 3):

Otra opción:

Tal y como lo tienes con una pequeña modificación puedes conseguir el resultado esperado. Simplemente pon en el `value` de `prop` una expresión que evalúe el `length` de los `checkboxes` que están `checked`. Te paso el ejemplo. He puesto también una clase a los `checkbox` para asegurarte que los que compruebas son esos y no otros `checkboxes` que pudieras tener en tu `DOM`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk1" class="chkSubmit"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk2" class="chkSubmit"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk3" class="chkSubmit"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk4" class="chkSubmit"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk5" class="chkSubmit"/>
<input type="submit" value="Enviar" id="sub" disabled="true"/>
<hr/>
<p>Otros checkboxes que no hacen nada en el botón submit</p>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk6"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk7"/>
 <script>
 $(function(){
   $("input:checkbox.chkSubmit").on('change', function() {
  $('#sub').prop("disabled",$($("input:checkbox.chkSubmit").is(":checked")).length == 0);
   }).trigger('change'); 
 });
 
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola primero que todo debes saber sobre los selectores de javascript (o si usa Jquery)(imagino que ya lo sabes).

Luego debes preguntar por un listener al evento de check y colocar una clase en cada uno de ellos ´ ´ reeemplazas '@id=" + id + "'  por tu clase y te queda listo. Espero te sirva.

Jeison.

```
function isCheckedById(id) {
  alert(id);
  var checked = $("input[@id=" + id + "]:checked").length;
  alert(checked);

  if (checked == 0) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```